# Branch Prediction and Random Processes (e.g. Monte Carlo)

Tags: c, random, branch-prediction

I came across a post on branch prediction ([Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array)) and it got me thinking about my own Monte Carlo simulations. For the sake of specificity, let's say we are working in C and writing for CPUs. (Does that matter?) Suppose you have a loop that goes something like this:

```
while ( condition ) {

    // dE will be stochastic...
    dE = MonteCarloMove();

    // ...and d is a random number between 0 and 1
    d = RandomRealNumber(0,1);

    w = exp(-dE);
    if ( dE < 0 || d < w ) {
        AcceptMonteCarloMove();
    }
    else {
        RejectMonteCarloMove();
    }
}
```

It seems to me that branch prediction at the `if..else` statement is completely useless, since it is random which way we go. In a properly designed Monte Carlo simulation, you'll have roughly as many accepts as rejections. So here are my questions:

- Is there any technique one could use to avoid the branching slowdown in a random process like this?
- If so, is it likely to provide any significant speed-up, considering that `MonteCarloMove()` probably involves some expensive numerical calculations?

**Update:** In case this general question is unanswerable, or the answer is generally no, suppose we can make some assumptions about the functions inside the `if` statement:

- `AcceptMonteCarloMove()` is a function that updates the current state of the simulation. All it likely needs to do is

  - Copy values from one variable to another;
  - Perform simple arithmetic (addition/subtraction).
- `RejectMonteCarloMove()` needs to reset the current state and possibly some bookkeeping variables. Likely it only needs to

  - Copy values from one variable to another.

Comment: You added three very different languages. Pick one. Especially for Java things can be very different here.

Comment: That's one thing I wanted to know. I restricted the question to C.

Comment: The answer strongly depends on what do `AcceptMontecarloMove` and `RejectMonteCarloMove` actually do. If they are sufficiently simple, there are techniques for removing this branching.

Comment: Note: the function calling overhead is larger than the failing branch prediction.

Comment: @joop OK, but these functions may be inlined and just assigning constants to a global variable.

Comment: @matb: or a conditional jsr is used. There are too many variables here. The question is far too broad.

Comment: @matb Thanks for the comments. I added some assumptions that could reasonably be made about the functions.

Comment: @joop That's already an interesting fact. Wouldn't that overhead be optimized out by a compiler, though?

Comment: The cure for a poor branch prediction is a conditional move.  That needs to start by generating a *bool* and an UpdateMonteCarloMove(bool) function.  With unspecified magic in that function that can take advantage of conditional moves.  The conditional operator is likely to generate it.  Pretty low odds that such a rather heavy-handed micro-optimization produces a measurably better outcome, you only save a handful of nanoseconds at best and that easily drowns in the time needed to execute the update function.

Comment: That single branch seems to be very insignificant compared to the amount of processing in the functions. If, and only if, you have found a performance problem, you should go look at the largest performance culprits, not at insignificant micro-optimizations. For example, replacing float numbers with integers would probably give a significant performance boost.

Comment: Also: the for functions inside the loop will contain conditions too. At least the move generator. Maybe the accept/deny choice is not even a real choice; both legs update the current state(s), so maybe they could be combined.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. They go a long way towards answering the question. If anyone wants to write them up in answer-form I'll happily accept it.